# facebook like page with url to application

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have been trying to create a Facebook like-page with a like linke/button to my iphone application. Like **Camera+** ([http://www.facebook.com/CamPl.us](http://www.facebook.com/CamPl.us?sk=info)). I just can't find anyway how to make a page like camera+ - Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this feature is outdated or disabled from facebook :-/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273559/how-do-i-change-download-app-button-url-for-facebook-app